# Apache forward proxy by url parameter

Tags: apache

I want redirect any access whose URL parameter is "deep" to local server, and redirect other access to other server. 
Forward a request like the following:

```
①　url parameter starting with deep
http*://hostname/bdd?deep=1
→
http*://127.0.0.1:8080/bdd
② other url 
→
http*://10.137.213.101:8080/bdd
```

I am setting my apache conf as the following, but it still does not work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^deep
RewriteRule "^/bdd(.*)$" /dataviewlinks/ [L]
ProxyPass /dataviewlinks http*://127.0.0.1:8080/bdd
ProxyPassReverse /dataviewlinks http*://127.0.0.1:8080/bdd

ProxyPass /bdd http*://10.137.213.101:8080/bdd
ProxyPassReverse /bdd http*://10.137.213.101:8080/bdd
```

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this in the past to redirect any network access on port 8080 to another directory.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1

    <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass "/" "http://10.137.213.101:8080/bdd"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://10.137.213.101:8080/bdd"
</VirtualHost>
```

Maybe this would work for you as well.

Also make sure you have enabled proxy mod `sudo a2enmod proxy` and restart apache

Comment: Thank you. That is not what I want. I want redirect any access whose URL parameter is "deep" to local server, and redirect other access to other server.

Comment: @Sekiichi Sorry, i dont know the answer for that. add that comment to your original post (in the actual post) and someone else might be able to help. your comment would make your question more clear.